# How to get the desired XML portion into variables with JQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Assuming I have the following example XML:

```
<PrimaryMembers>
<Member>
<Name>Jessica</Name>
<Hobby>Softball</Hobby>
</Member>
<SecondaryMembers>
<Member>
<Name>Wilson</Name>
<Hobby>Baseball</Hobby>
</Member>
<Member>
<Name>John</Name>
<Hobby>Soccer</Hobby>
</Member>
</SecondaryMembers>
</PrimaryMembers>
```

With JQuery, I want to be able to get JUST:

```
<Name>Jessica</Name>
<Hobby>Softball</Hobby>
```

into a name and hobby variable.

Assume that the string containing the xml is stored in a variable xml. How do I do this? I notice that every time I try to store just Jessica into a variable, it stores "JessicaWilsonJohn" into it.

I imagine it has to do with the

```
var name = $(xml).find("Something").text();
```

NOTE: I do NOT want to store Wilson and John. I only want to get just Jessica and Softball.

Comment: how are you trying to store???

Comment: Would JSON be a better data transfer format?

Comment: I agree, but for the sake of learing XML, I'm treating it as XML.

Answer (score 0):

```
var members = [];
$(xml).find('Name:contains(Jessica)').each(function(){
  var member = {};
  $(this).siblings().each(function(){
    member[this.nodeName] = $(this).text();
 });
  members.push(member);
});
```

However it looks like your XML has soem issues if its an accurate representation. The `PrimaryMembers` is missing a closing tag. Also, while not a deal breaker it seems that each `Name`/`Hobby` should be contained by a `Member` element, which is not the case across the document.

> NOTE: I do NOT want to store Wilson and John. I only want to get just Jessica and Softball.

Well youre actually making a bad presumption here. There is no guarantee that "Jessica" will be unique so you may not have only one result. With that said you could do the following:

```
function getMember(memberName){
 var properties = {};
 $(xml).find('Name:contains("'+memberName+'")').siblings().each(function(){
    properties[this.nodeName] = $(this).text();
 });
 return properties;
};

var theMember = getMember('Jessica');
```

Comment: you should .find() member objects, not names. The sample should probably have <member> around the primary too.

Comment: @Emyr: It should but it didnt.. i even called that out in my response. Worth a comment surely, but i dunno about a down vote.

Comment: Assuming there were other attributes beisdes name and hobby, wouldnt it be inconvenient to do: 

member.attribc = $(this).next('Hobby').next('C').text();
member.attribd = $(this).next('Hobby').next('C').next('D').text();

Comment: @Teviere: Absolutely. If that were the case then it would be better to use `element.siblings(attrName)` or something similar. But without know the **real** structure of the XML its kind of hard to make that decision (though with siblings it wouldnt make a difference). If you clean up the XML and make it accurate id be happy to update my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the XML based on your feedback, let me know if you feel this is accurate or any additional changes should be made.

Comment: @Teviere: Well if you are in control of the XML i would make the structure look like `<Members><PrimaryMembers></PrimaryMembers><SecondaryMembers></SecondaryMembers></Members>` because your secondary shouldnt be logically be nested within the primary as they are both different sets of members and not a parent/child relationship.

Comment: Im actually not in control of the XML, but essentially there is a parent child relationsip where you can think of Jessica as like the team captain/class president or something like that. So structurewise, I am still restricted to it.

Comment: Well as long as all the attributes are contained within a `Member` for each member you shouldnt have any problems. it jsut means if you want to only search `PrimaryMembers` youd need to use a selector like `PrimaryMembers > Member:contains(Jessica)` as opposed to `PrimaryMembers Member:contains(Jessica)'